# Running webpack-cli --force still ask questions... how to generate a project without interaction?

Tags: webpack

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/packages/generators/INIT.md) one should be able to initialize a project without any question running `npx webpack-cli init --force`. For me, it still ask for question:

```
root@3c8ae34bbe9b:/var/www/html# npx webpack-cli init --force
[webpack-cli] For using this command you need to install: '@webpack-cli/generators' package.
[webpack-cli] Would you like to install '@webpack-cli/generators' package? (That will run 'npm install -D @webpack-cli/generators') (Y/n)
```

Any way to generate a project without interaction?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The issue has been solved by webpack-cli team and me, see this link and try it now if it works (if not, then wait for update): [Running npx webpack-cli --force still ask questions... #3719](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/3719)

Use:

```
npm install -D @webpack-cli/generators
```

And try it again.

If it does not work, use the follow command:

```
npx webpack-cli init --force --no-install
```

and do it again.

If its still same, then, you should issue to this link: [webpack-cli github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues).